SpresenseへのSWDデバッガでの書き込みがうまくいかない
Spresense拡張ボードのCN1にSWDデバッガを接続してプログラムを書き込もうとしています。
GDBのloadコマンドを使用して書き込みが成功したように見えるのですが、Spresenseメインボードのリセットボタンを押すと、書き込んだはずのプログラムが実行されず、以前にArduino IDEで書き込んでいたプログラムが実行されてしまいます。
環境：
・SWDデバッガ：Raspberry Pi Debug Probe
・ホストOS：Windows11（WSL2）
・OpenOCDのバージョン：0.12.0+dev-00699-ge09bb72da
・GDBのバージョン：10.2.90.20210621-git
問題の説明：
SpresenseのボードをホストマシンにSWDデバッガを介して接続しています。
書き込もうとしている実行ファイルはSpresense SDKのサンプルプログラム"Hello, World!"をビルドしたものになります。
以下に実行した手順を示します。

PowerShellコマンド：
CMSIS-DAPのBUSID（1-7）を指定してSTATEをAttachedに変更しています。

usbipd attach -w -b 1-7


OpenOCDコマンド
WSL2のターミナルを開いて実行しています。

cd spresense/sdk
openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f tools/cxd5602.cfg


GDBコマンド：
別のWSL2のターミナルを開いて実行しています。

cd spresense/sdk
arm-none-eabi-gdb nuttx
(gdb) target remote localhost:3333
(gdb) monitor reset halt
(gdb) load


loadコマンドの出力：

(gdb) load
Loading section .text, size 0x294e4 lma 0xd000000
Loading section .ARM.exidx, size 0x8 lma 0xd0294e4
Loading section .data, size 0x544 lma 0xd0294f0
Start address 0x0d000240, load size 170544
Transfer rate: 62 KB/sec, 13118 bytes/write.

質問：

書き込みが成功したように見えるのに、リセット後にArduino IDEで書き込んだプログラムが実行される原因は何でしょうか？
書き込んだプログラムを正しく実行させるために必要な設定や手順があれば教えてください。
OpenOCDやGDBの設定に問題がある可能性はありますか？


SpresenseプログラムはFlashからの直接実行(XIP)ではなく
FlashからSRAMへプログラムを展開してから実行されます。
gdb経由のloadコマンドはSRAMへのロードを行うのみなので、
load後にcontinueコマンド等でプログラムを実行し、
ロードしたプログラムをデバッグすることは可能ですが、
揮発性のSRAMへロードされているだけなので、
リセットすると再びFlash内に保存されたプログラムが起動されます。
Flashへのプログラム書き込みは、ELF形式ではなくspkというフォーマットに
変換されたファイルを flash_writer という PC ツールで書き込むようになっており、
アプリケーションCPUやGDB経由でFlashへプログラムを直接書き込むことはできないようです。
